# How to replace a string which start without ">"?

Tags: linux, text, awk, sed

I have some text files which look like this:

```
>KZ289077.1 PWK_PHJ_MMCHR11_CTG1
>KZ289078.1 PWK_PHJ_MMCHR11_CTG2
>KZ289079.1 PWK_PHJ_MMCHR11_CTG3
>KZ289073.1 WSB_EIJ_MMCHR11_CTG1
GAGGAGAGGGAGAGGAGAGGGAGAGGAGAGGAGAGGGGAGRGGAGGGGGGGAGGGGAGGG
GCAGAACTGGGATTAGATCTTCTKTGAAGGTCTGATAGAACTCTGCACTAAACCCATCTG
GAAACTTCTCMATTTCATCCAGGTTCTCCAGTTTTGTTGAGTATAGCCTTTTGTAGAAGG
GGAGAGGGAGAGGAGAGGGAGAGGAGAGGAGAGGGGAGRGGAGGGGGGGAGGGGAGGGGA
TGAATTTGGGTCCTTCCCCAGGCAACCTCACGTGATGATACCTTCTTGGGGGGGGGGGRG
>KZ289074.1 WSB_EIJ_MMCHR11_CTG2
TAGTTGTTGCTAGGGTAACACGGTTGGGTTTTTTTTCCAGTATCTGAGTTCATTCTAAKG
>KZ289075.1 WSB_EIJ_MMCHR11_CTG3
```

I would like to replace all "R" characters in the lines not starting with ">" with "A". I have tried the following code:

```
awk '$0~/^!">"/ {gsub(/R/,"A")}1' kk.txt
```

But it does not work. The ideal result should be like this:

```
>KZ289077.1 PWK_PHJ_MMCHR11_CTG1
>KZ289078.1 PWK_PHJ_MMCHR11_CTG2
>KZ289079.1 PWK_PHJ_MMCHR11_CTG3
>KZ289073.1 WSB_EIJ_MMCHR11_CTG1
GAGGAGAGGGAGAGGAGAGGGAGAGGAGAGGAGAGGGGAGAGGAGGGGGGGAGGGGAGGG
GCAGAACTGGGATTAGATCTTCTKTGAAGGTCTGATAGAACTCTGCACTAAACCCATCTG
GAAACTTCTCMATTTCATCCAGGTTCTCCAGTTTTGTTGAGTATAGCCTTTTGTAGAAGG
GGAGAGGGAGAGGAGAGGGAGAGGAGAGGAGAGGGGAGAGGAGGGGGGGAGGGGAGGGGA
TGAATTTGGGTCCTTCCCCAGGCAACCTCACGTGATGATACCTTCTTGGGGGGGGGGGAG
>KZ289074.1 WSB_EIJ_MMCHR11_CTG2
TAGTTGTTGCTAGGGTAACACGGTTGGGTTTTTTTTCCAGTATCTGAGTTCATTCTAAKG
>KZ289075.1 WSB_EIJ_MMCHR11_CTG3
```

Could anyone give me a hint? Thanks : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small change should do:

```
awk '!/^>/ {gsub(/R/,"A")}1' file
```

Line that do not start with `>` replace `R` with `A`

Comment: You are the best! Thank you ; )

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with sed

```
sed '/^[^>]/s/R/A/g' your_file
            | | | |_ globally
            | | |____replace with
            | |______replace this
            |________sed mode search and replace
```

The `^` inside the square brackets means `not`, outside of it it means `beginning of the line`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and a helpful explanation. Have a good day : )

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^>/!y/R/A/' file
```

For all lines not starting with `>` transpose `R` to `A`.